# Xcode Server OTA Install: "cannot connect to server.local"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, continuous-integration, osx-server

I cannot get the `"Over The Air"` installation of iOS apps to work using the latest version of **macOS (10.12.5)** and `Xcode Server (5.3.1)`. I can create Xcode Bots and the integrate without any issue, but it always fails with **"cannot connect to server.local"** when trying to install the app from any device.
The **"Xcode Server OTA Installation"** profile is installed.
I can download the archive and product using Safari on the Mac without a problem.
In summary, everything work but the OTA installation always fails.

Tried on two different Macs already, also with a complete clean installation of macOS before.

**Versions: macOS 10.12.5, Xcode 8.3.2 and Server 5.3.1**

I found several old reports of this problem but all the workarounds didn't seem to help.

**Same problem on Xcode 9 beta 1 with the now built-in Xcode server.**

Comment: Is your server name really "server.local"?

Comment: no, it's actually "ci.local" but tried it on other computers with different names as well. same issue. the error message is "cannot connect to ci.local" or whatever the server name is.

Comment: Ah alright, just wanted to get the obvious out of the way; I'll assume the certs you've created are all `ci.local` too...

Comment: It's a self-signed certificate created by the Xcode server. I did not create any certificates myself.

Comment: Can you check if either the certificate has expired or is using SHA-1?

Comment: And the same problem on a complete clean install of macOS 10.12 with Xcode 9 and the (now built-in) Xcode server ...

Comment: Try a fresh re-installation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For ***iOS 10.3 and later***, a reason why fails, in some cases, with "Cannot connect to *.local" is that self-signed certificate shall be trusted manually in Settings on test devices (eg. iPhone).

Steps as follow:

1. Install self-signed certificate(s) from Xcode server's bots page on your iPhone;
2. Go to iPhone's `Settings`->`General`->`About`->`Certificate Trust Settings`;
3. Find your server's self-signed certificate(s) under section `ENABLE FULL TRUST FOR ROOT CERTIFICATES`, and turn the switch ON;
4. Visit bots page on Xcode Server, click install.

Answer (score 0):

My SSL certificate had expired thats why happened to me. Make sure you add that to the list of things to check. Once I renewed that it started working again.

Comment: self-signed certificate or one from certain authority?

Comment: You can create self-signed certificate

Comment: Try this:
- use another email account on the iPhone
- email the self signed (root) certificate to your mail account on the phone
- open the email and tap the attachment (cert)
- tap install on the top right hand corner and complete installation

Comment: It might help not sure

Comment: My problem is the same as @slurmomatic, brand new installed macOS Server with auto-created self-signed certificate (no way to be expired), but doesn't work. (My macOS server is deployed in a local network.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Xcode9 GM. I have installed profile on the Xcode server page and trust the profile. Is this a signing error? I use "export: installable product" for server bot.